# dynamically created controls ID's in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

im creating a dynamic table, when i click "add" button a row will be added with four cells created dynamically, first cell conatins a checkbox created dynamically,rest of the cells contains textboxes created dynamically.
 the id's allocated are

```
    Table Table1 = new Table();
    TableRow row = new TableRow();
    TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
    TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
    TableCell cell3 = new TableCell();
    TableCell cell4 = new TableCell();
    CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox();
    TextBox textbox1 = new TextBox();
    TextBox textbox2 = new TextBox();
    TextBox textbox3 = new TextBox();
    row.ID = "row" + Table1.Rows.Count;
    cell1.ID = "cell1" + Table1.Rows.Count;
    cell2.ID = "cell2" + Table1.Rows.Count;
    cell3.ID = "cell3" + Table1.Rows.Count;
    cell4.ID = "cell4" + Table1.Rows.Count;
    checkbox.ID = "ck1" + Table1.Rows.Count;
    textbox1.ID = "tb1" + Table1.Rows.Count;
    textbox2.ID = "tb2" + Table1.Rows.Count;
    textbox3.ID = "tb3" + Table1.Rows.Count;
```

i have another delete button,
when i select any the checkboxes of the rows and click the delete buttons the particluar selected rows are deleted and the table count also decreasing, but again when i click the add button  im getting an error such as row cannot be created because already a row existing with that id, kindly help me in this issue

example:
i created 6 rows vth id:"row1","row2","row3","row4","row5","row6"

im deleting im deleting row3,row5,row6, now the present rows are row1,row2,row4.
then im adding another row, now im getting error as "new row cannot be added beacause a row vth id row4 is already existing", please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You could re-id all the rows/cells every time you delete a row.

Or you could use a counter, say MaxRow, that you would store in session state and new rows would use that instead of Rows.Count.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you don't add the rows to the table (it's not shown in your code at least), table1.rows.count will not increment for the next row to be added.  So that is probably why you are getting the error message.

I think it might be more important to ask yourself why you feel you need to assign ID's to each element in this way, though.  I think would be much more manageable to use collection indexers and `FindControl()` to find the element you want to work with.  If you use this method, each element could have the same server-side ID within its container.

This way, you can mathematically work your way through the table using the `int` indexer(s) rather than having to increment string-based ID's.

For instance (perhaps in a for loop):

`(TextBox)WorkingControl = Table1.Rows(i).Cells(j).FindControl("tb1");
 WorkingControl.Text = 'Hello';`

Please excuse my C#, it's a little rough.  Hopefully you get the idea.